# How can I transfer the following language into an context-free grammar?

Tags: context-free

[image: {a^n b^m c^k | n > m + k}]

My problem of understanding is how to create a new a before the b's if you create new c's.

Hopefully someone can help me out.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755

Comment: Please don't use images of text or math.  This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Answer (score -1):

You can firstly spawn $k$ letter $c$'s providing an $a$ for every $c$ spawned, then start putting $m$ $b$'s between $a$ and $c$ adding $a$ for every $b$. Also letter $a$ can be created any number of times after all $b$ and $c$ letters are created. This approach can be done with the following CFG:
$$G = (V, \Sigma, S, R), \: V = \{S, A, B, B', C, C'\} \cup \Sigma,$$
and the rules are
$$R = 
\begin{cases}
S \to AC, \\
S \to AB, \\ 
C \to ACC', \\
C \to AC', \\
C \to ABC', \\
B \to ABB', \\
B \to AB', \\
C' \to c, \\
C' \to e, \\
B' \to b, \\
B' \to e, \\
A \to Aa, \\
A \to a.
\end{cases}$$
This grammar is definetely not the most beautiful and short, I have put some safety checks there. However, it demonstrates the idea of my solution.